# Xcode Reality Composer Crashes With Face or Image Anchor (SwiftUI app)

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality

I started to build a new AR app and whenever I attempt to create a new scene in
Reality Composer with an Image or Face anchor Reality Composer crashes. If I use
a vertical or horizontal anchor it does not crash. My main coding is on
my iMacPro1,1.

However, on my MacBook Air (M1, 2020) the app does NOT crash.

Both machines are macOS Monterey 12.3.1, both have Xcode 13.4 which includes Reality
Composer 1.5.

I deleted Xcode.app and reinstalled it but did not attempt to find/delete any
other associated files. I have to assume that there are other setup or support files
that must be corrupted but cannot find any info to point me to a solution.

This is the error screen:

[image]

The Reason and Process are listed as the following, but that has not helped me:

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [30727]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Sadly, no. macOS 12.4 came out and I hoped without reason an update would fix this, but no.

Comment: Apparently they mentioned that the crash is a known issue in their Xcode 13.4 release notes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_4-release-notes

Comment: Their description: Using the Reality Composer app or previewing Reality Composer projects in Xcode may lead to a crash on Mac systems with AMD GPU: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016), MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019), iMac Pro (2017). (92637801)

Workaround: Use Xcode 13.3.